# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView column width

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to make a Windows Phone page with 2 columns, where the columns fill all of their space to make rectangular buttons similar to the Windows Phone menu. Surprisingly, this is trickier than expected. I have the layout working, and the 2 columns, however, they are small rectangles, not filling their width or height.

I don't want to use any "Width = 250" or whatever. I'm purely interested in a responsive layout solution. My current code is below. I've been here for about 2 days now...

```
    <ListView
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="12">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Margin="12"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                                    <Image />
                                    <TextBlock
                                    TextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" 
                          MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" 
                          HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Here's a screenshot of what it currently looks like. As you can see, the buttons have a massive margin that is not actually given by me...

http://gyazo.com/3c949bd9a6ac5d08b3e40bd5c9bb0e7b

Answer (score 0):

As you say it looks like you do have two columns in your picture.  I'm also seeing from your markup that you have 12 pixels margin on your list and 12 pixels margin on your buttons.  That means that you're going to have at least 24 pixels of margin between all your UI elements.  Looking at the picture I'm seeing closer to 60 pixels between UI elements.  We should break this down further to see where the extra size is coming from.

For debugging purposes can you please add a temporary background color to your ListView and a different background color to your DataTemplate item's StackPanel.  Then take a new screenshot and see what elements are consuming all the space.  I bet it's the ListViewItem.  You might want modify the [ItemContainerStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to remove any built in non-visible UI elements taking up space.

Comment: Here you go. The ListView background is White, and the StackPanel background Red. Button being PhoneAccentColor, which is blue: http://gyazo.com/83455afd42b8b971ea3cd5c2336f6f55